# Is there an easier way to update all the dates in MongoDb in different formats (String) to date?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, date, nosql

I have a date field which has values in different formats, sometimes in `"dd-mm-yyyy"`, sometimes in `"yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:S.fZ"` and sometimes in date type.

I want to get them all in the date format.

So far I have tried :

1. matching string and non-string types (using $facet) and merging them.- facet working memory ran out.
2. Running a for each loop and filtering on id and updating with new date.

   `db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
   bulkUpdateOps.push({
   "updateOne": {
   "filter": {"_id": doc._id},
   "update": {"$set": {"myDate": new Date(doc.myDate)}}
   }
   })

   ```
   if (bulkUpdateOps.length === 1000) {
       db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps)
       bulkUpdateOps=[]
   }
   ```

   })`

This is also dying after processing about 20-30% records. I have millions of records in this collection.

**tl:dr** - Want to convert all string dates to date type in a mongodb collection with miilions of records.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   { myDate: { $type: "string" } }, 
   [
      { $set: { myDate: { $toDate: "$myDate" } } }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess simplest solutions are always better.